# why isn't my included library project recognized in xml file? Using Library Projects correctly

Tags: android, xml, shared-libraries

I need to use a `library project` in my project.

But for some reasons a

```
referenced XML prefix is not recognized.
```

Here are the steps I did to add the library project:

1. Project -> properties -> Android -> added the library project
2. in my project created a folder lib_src -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Link Source (to the src folder of the library project)

But the problem is that a used XML reference to the linked library project is not being recognized.

Please help - what did I do wrong when trying to use this library project?

this is the xml file portion in my project with the unrecognized reference:

```
 <org.taptwo.android.widget.CircleFlowIndicator
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/viewflowindic"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:inactiveType="fill"
        app:fadeOut="1000" />
```

where  `<org.taptwo.android.widget.CircleFlowIndicator` causes the problem.

However I have a linked library folder `lib_src` with the sub-folder:
`org.taptwo.android.widget` and the contained class file `CircleFlowIndicator.java` in my project.

I also have exactly this folder added to my build path.

Please give some advice what could be the reason that I keep getting the problem:

`Error parsing XML: unbound prefix` at `<org.taptwo.android.widget.CircleFlowIndicator`

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that your second step of manually selecting a source folder is necessary.

I think the point of the library referencing in the project's properties is to sort it out for you automatically. Try following the steps exactly as they are here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html

Perhaps a clean and build in Eclipse of all the projects involved might help if your settings are correct.

(Also, you didn't mention selecting 'is library' in the library project's properties, so make sure that's done if you haven't already done it)

Comment: thanks for this - but that's exactly what I did + the linking of the source code - I keep getting the same problem - I am getting crazy... Another project in my workspace successfully included the library project I am trying to use. I just don't know where's the trick...

Comment: I finally figured it out - this is quite a stupid error having to do with incompatiblities of new Eclipse & APIs with older projects from the publicly available libs. The best way to avoid I found is NOT to create project from existing files BUT create NEW projects and then INSERT the file structure - otherwise strange things might happen - I wasted couple of hours on that:(

Comment: That sounds very silly indeed, what a shame we still have these kinds of issues after so long. Glad you sorted it out :-)